# Is there a method in selenium to load a page without blocking the script?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My problem is that all the code after `driver.get(url)` get blocked until the page has been completely loaded.I do not want this behaviour,so is there any other method I can use ?? or maybe an option to put the get method in non-blocking mode?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and I worked around the problem by calling driver.get in another Thread:

```
import threading
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
t = threading.Thread(target=driver.get, args=(url,))
t.start()
# do stuff while page is loading...
t.join()  # join() will block until page is done loading
# now the page is done loading.
```